# akka cluster seed nodes give error: dropping message for non-local recipient

Tags: scala, akka, actor, akka-cluster

I'm trying to create a basic akka cluster on a Win 7 machine from this documentation:
http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/cluster-usage.html

and I'm getting an error when I run the seed nodes (more on them below)

> AdriansClusterSystem-akka.actor.default-dispa tcher-16]
>   [akka://AdriansClusterSystem/system/endpointManager/reliableEndpointWr
>   iter-akka.tcp%3A%2F%2FAdriansClusterSystem%40127.0.0.1%3A2552-3/endpointWriter]
>   dropping message [class akka.actor.SelectChildName] for non-local
>   recipient [Act or[akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@127.0.0.1:2552/]] arriving
>   at [akka.tcp://ClusterSys tem@127.0.0.1:2552] inbound addresses are
>   [akka.tcp://AdriansClusterSystem@127.0 .0.1:2552]

**Question:**
Why am I getting this error? Did I miss something from the akka documentation?

My .conf file:
I added this extra line *To the file listed at the URL above *
`enabled-transports = ["akka.remote.netty.tcp"]`

```
akka {
  actor {
    provider = "akka.cluster.ClusterActorRefProvider"
  }
  remote {
    enabled-transports = ["akka.remote.netty.tcp"]  <--added this from remoting
    log-remote-lifecycle-events = off
    netty.tcp {
      hostname = "127.0.0.1"
      port = 0
    }
  }
  cluster {
    seed-nodes = [
    "akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@127.0.0.1:2551",
    "akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@127.0.0.1:2552"]

  auto-down = on
  }
}
```

I start the 2 nodes, each in different sbt windows

> ```
> run-main sample.cluster.simple.SimpleClusterApp 2551  
> run-main sample.cluster.simple.SimpleClusterApp 2552
> ```

Both of these start up fine then repeatedly show an `ERROR` message:

```
mybuild:-:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT>`run-main sample.cluster.simple.SimpleClusterApp 2552`
[warn] Credentials file C:\Users\amocanu\.ivy2\.credentials does not exist  <-- ?
[info] Running sample.cluster.simple.SimpleClusterApp 2552
 args[0]= 2552
[INFO] [07/31/2013 10:50:00.397] [run-main] [Remoting] Starting remoting
[INFO] [07/31/2013 10:50:00.661] [run-main] [Remoting] Remoting started; listeni
ng on addresses :[akka.tcp://AdriansClusterSystem@127.0.0.1:2552]
[INFO] [07/31/2013 10:50:00.710] [run-main] [Cluster(akka://AdriansClusterSystem
)] Cluster Node [akka.tcp://AdriansClusterSystem@127.0.0.1:2552] - Starting up..
.
[INFO] [07/31/2013 10:50:00.823] [run-main] [Cluster(akka://AdriansClusterSystem
)] Cluster Node [akka.tcp://AdriansClusterSystem@127.0.0.1:2552] - Registered cl
uster JMX MBean [akka:type=Cluster]
[INFO] [07/31/2013 10:50:00.823] [run-main] [Cluster(akka://AdriansClusterSystem
)] Cluster Node [akka.tcp://AdriansClusterSystem@127.0.0.1:2552] - Started up su
ccessfully
[INFO] [07/31/2013 10:50:00.868] [AdriansClusterSystem-akka.actor.default-dispat
cher-2] [Cluster(akka://AdriansClusterSystem)] Cluster Node [akka.tcp://AdriansC
lusterSystem@127.0.0.1:2552] - Metrics will be retreived from MBeans, and may be
 incorrect on some platforms. To increase metric accuracy add the 'sigar.jar' to
 the classpath and the appropriate platform-specific native libary to 'java.libr
ary.path'. Reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hyperic.sigar.Sigar
[INFO] [07/31/2013 10:50:00.874] [AdriansClusterSystem-akka.actor.default-dispat
cher-2] [Cluster(akka://AdriansClusterSystem)] Cluster Node [akka.tcp://AdriansC
lusterSystem@127.0.0.1:2552] - Metrics collection has started successfully
[INFO] [07/31/2013 10:50:00.883] [AdriansClusterSystem-akka.actor.default-dispat
cher-13] [akka://AdriansClusterSystem/user/clusterListener] Current members:
[ERROR] [07/31/2013 10:50:01.003] [AdriansClusterSystem-akka.actor.default-dispa
tcher-3] [akka://AdriansClusterSystem/system/endpointManager/reliableEndpointWri
ter-akka.tcp%3A%2F%2FAdriansClusterSystem%40127.0.0.1%3A2551-0/endpointWriter] d
ropping message [class akka.actor.SelectChildName] for non-local recipient [Acto
r[akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@127.0.0.1:2552/]] arriving at [akka.tcp://ClusterSyst
em@127.0.0.1:2552] inbound addresses are [akka.tcp://AdriansClusterSystem@127.0.
0.1:2552]
[ERROR] [07/31/2013 10:50:01.009] [AdriansClusterSystem-akka.actor.default-dispa
tcher-16] [akka://AdriansClusterSystem/system/endpointManager/reliableEndpointWr
iter-akka.tcp%3A%2F%2FAdriansClusterSystem%40127.0.0.1%3A2552-3/endpointWriter]
dropping message [class akka.actor.SelectChildName] for non-local recipient [Act
or[akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@127.0.0.1:2552/]] arriving at [akka.tcp://ClusterSys
tem@127.0.0.1:2552] inbound addresses are [akka.tcp://AdriansClusterSystem@127.0
.0.1:2552]
```

If now I do

> ```
> run-main sample.cluster.simple.SimpleClusterApp
> ```

which is supposed to choose a random port and run a seed node on, it starts of well just as the other 2 seed nodes, then shows a class not found exception as `INFO` and no current members

```
[INFO] [07/31/2013 11:19:36.612] [AdriansClusterSystem-akka.actor.default-dispat
cher-3] [Cluster(akka://AdriansClusterSystem)] Cluster Node [akka.tcp://AdriansC
lusterSystem@127.0.0.1:54824] - Metrics will be retreived from MBeans, and may b
e incorrect on some platforms. To increase metric accuracy add the 'sigar.jar' t
o the classpath and the appropriate platform-specific native libary to 'java.lib
rary.path'. Reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hyperic.sigar.Sigar
[INFO] [07/31/2013 11:19:36.619] [AdriansClusterSystem-akka.actor.default-dispat
cher-3] [Cluster(akka://AdriansClusterSystem)] Cluster Node [akka.tcp://AdriansC
lusterSystem@127.0.0.1:54824] - Metrics collection has started successfully
[INFO] [07/31/2013 11:19:36.633] [AdriansClusterSystem-akka.actor.default-dispat
cher-12] [akka://AdriansClusterSystem/user/clusterListener] Current members:
```

Yup it just hangs there and I have to close the sbt window to terminate it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It looks like your seed nodes are using `ClusterSystem` as the actor system name but according to your logs you are using `AdriansClusterSystem` as your actor system name.  Try changing the seed nodes to:

```
seed-nodes = [
"akka.tcp://AdriansClusterSystem@127.0.0.1:2551",
"akka.tcp://AdriansClusterSystem@127.0.0.1:2552"]
```

Comment: I feel like an idiot right now. Thanks that was it, I've been changing lots of settings and forgot about this one change. Another pair of eyes always helps :)

Answer (score 1):

For the benefit of searchers...

Firstly, check the accepted answer from @cmbaxter.

However, if that fails:

- Run your cluster and copy the address of the seed node e.g. `akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@localhost:8092/system/endpointManager/...`
- Now check the address in the error e.g. `Dropping message [Akka.Actor.ActorSelectionMessage] for non-local recipient [[akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@127.0.0.1:8092/]]`

In my case, `ClusterSystem` was set up on `localhost`, but the calling code was calling `127.0.0.1`.

Setting client and cluster (including seed-nodes) to the same address fixed it (I set both to `127.0.0.1)`